# ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh Permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

i try to instal mavros in ros kinetic ubuntu 16.04, but i cannot install

```
$ ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh
bash: ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh: Permission denied
```

I tried:

```
sudo chmod -x ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh
```

but it doesn't fix that permission. what should i do to fix this??

Comment: `chmod -x` makes it executable, it doesn't change permissions. If the script is meant to be run as root you still have to use `sudo`. Try that and [edit] and update your question if necessary.

Comment: `chmod +x`, not `chmod -x`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you had to do `sudo chmod -x ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh` means the script has to be run using `sudo`. And like has been stated by MichaelBay the command `chmod +x` only adds the `execute` bit to the script but doesn't change the ownership which will determine who has permission to run it.

So run the script like so `sudo ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh`, and it should go well.

Based on muru's splendid observation, you need to rerun `sudo chmod +x ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh`, as `sudo chmod -x` removed the ability to execute that script.